# Can't install openjdk8-jre in Docker Alpine Linux image

Tags: docker, java, alpine-linux

Alpine 3.7 and 3.9. `apk add htop` works fine. `apk add openjdk8-jre` hangs forever. Problem step:

```
(25/36) Installing openjdk8-jre-lib (8.201.08-r0)
usr/ (dir)
usr/lib/ (dir)
usr/lib/jvm/ (dir)
usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/ (dir)
usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/jre/ (dir)
usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/jre/THIRD_PARTY_README
usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/jre/LICENSE
usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/jre/lib/ (dir)
usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/jre/lib/jsse.jar
usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/jre/lib/rt.jar
```

Here's the `strace` output:

```
writev(1, [{iov_base="\338\33[0K\0337 54% ###################"..., iov_len=198}, {iov_base=NULL, iov_len=0} 54% #####################################################################################################                                                                                    ) = 198
read(7, "\33\225\360$Vq\345\373\3117\300bi\373\206\345\v\254\225\226\344\217\324\251\332\267\224uY4\24\353"..., 8192) = 318
...[truncated a bunch more read(7, ... commands]
read(7, "\345\321\\L\270\266dD5&\3728\345lfj\7\t\341\345\235\317\336\370\334\20P\266\na\200\30"..., 4047) = 4044
read(7, "& e", 3)                       = 3
read(7, "\330\5,\tIj*\264W\356i\243\326\32\277\10\216\t\216\25\346\237\314?kd\276e\227\2233\333"..., 8192) = 531
read(7, "\r\241\306\205\3\325h\257&\242\312\341\24%\2331V.\223)\251\262=\v\314\20i\312\375\10r/"..., 7661) = 1348
read(7, "\235\2\333t\266\247\211\253Q*\207\205\v\34\351\231@#s\332\244\261\3321\247\264\253eBP\26z"..., 6313) = 5122
read(7, "T\314E\236\r\31g5d\234\325\20\377\25*\365\305\236\251'X\251'\330\2517\253\324\227x\246\236"..., 1191) = 1191
read(7, "T\256\376J\337%\vU\1\306\333\244l\4\376\225\323\21#\336'S\211nW@@\5/\31\1R"..., 8192) = 4941
read(7, "\6L\373\300\20\231>\2\263e*\312\267\342\344\210r\221\212r\221\356\205w\341=\274\277\1\362\345\265"..., 3251) = 1419
read(7, "\3514qz\362\346.2RPB\301[\3753\251\323B\272 uF\354\224\356*j'N{\2308"..., 1832) = 1460
read(7, "|\340\311C\255a\237+\17\301s()fHw\375\n\244\242<\221a\2p|\354\331\332\307\236\255"..., 372) = 372
read(7, "In(\231IC\263J\322\203i+\371\235@o\21\210\341\5\217;\222k7\79\233\263Q\265\34"..., 8192) = 1007
read(7,
```

It hangs on that last line as written and does nothing. How can I fix this?

**Edit**: this problem is definitely due to the nonsense proxies that we have set up at work. When I build on my work laptop from home, the problem disappears. It's unclear to me *why* our proxies cause this, but I don't really need an answer to that.

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce myself. How about `apk add openjdk8`?

Comment: @valiano, it gets further along, but still hangs eventually (see edited question)

Comment: To everyone viewing this in the future, just note that the problem was due to proxies I had set up at my work. I have no idea what those problems were, and digging down this deep was **not** worthwhile. I don't have any answers for you. Best of luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's difficult to tell what is going wrong exactly, without being able to reproduce, but you may be able to get a good idea using `strace`. It will generate a lot of output, but once it hangs, you should be able to tell from the last few lines what is keeping `apk` from proceeding - waiting on a file, lock, etc.

For running `strace`, add `--cap-add=SYS_PTRACE` to your `docker run` command and install strace with `apk add strace`. Then, run `strace apk add openjdk8-jre-lib`.

Alternatively, if the issue is only with the OpenJDK package and you're willing use a different base image, `openjdk:8-jdk-alpine3.9` (or similar) may fit your needs. This image is basically Alpine 3.9 + the openjdk8 package. In both variations, image size is 101-105MB.
Note you get slightly different OpenJDK builds - `1.8.0_201` from Alpine 3.9 + `openjdk8`, and `1.8.0_191` from `openjdk:8-jdk-alpine3.9`.

Comment: Unfortunately, the docker base image is not my decision, and because it can build via gitlab it's not going to be changed. I added the `strace` output (well, some of it). I have no idea how to read it because it looks like total garbage. If you have any more advice I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: @jeremysprofile Got it. According to strace the read from file handle 7 is stuck. Using the following command, you could check what file is mapped to this handle: `ls -la /proc/$$/fd`. In one docker, run the `strace apk add openjdk8-jre-lib` until it gets stuck; then, in a second console, connect to the same image using `sudo docker exec -i -t [image-id]`, and run the `ls` command.